# Data Transfer Manipulation (WinSock2 / NtDeviceIoControlFile)

Tags: c, winapi, winsock, ntdll

I'm trying to write a library that will intercept a data transfer in the current process (not mine) for further manipulation. My task is to make sure that the library that I embed in the process can decide whether to skip data further or not, moreover, do it in such a way that the client does not suspect anything.

Empirically, I found out that all data transfer functions (**[send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send)** / **[recv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-recv)** / **[WSASend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasend)** / **[WSARecv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsarecv)** etc.) ultimately lead to the **[NtDeviceIoControlFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntdeviceiocontrolfile)** function from the **ntdll.dll** library. In `IoControlCode` you can see what exactly is happening.

```
#define IOCTL_AFD_RECV   0x12017
#define IOCTL_AFD_SEND   0x1201F
#define IOCTL_AFD_SELECT 0x12024
```

On the Internet, I managed to find these two structures.

```
struct AFD_WSABUF
{
    UINT len;
    PCHAR buf;
};

struct AFD_INFO
{
    AFD_WSABUF* BufferArray;
    ULONG BufferCount;
    ULONG AfdFlags;
    ULONG TdiFlags;
};
```

With the imitation of a successful send, I seem to have coped.

```
// Intercepted function NtDeviceIOControlFile
int WINAPI myNtDeviceIoControlFile(
    HANDLE FileHandle,
    HANDLE Event,
    PIO_APC_ROUTINE ApcRoutine,
    PVOID ApcContext,
    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    ULONG IoControlCode,
    PVOID InputBuffer,
    ULONG InputBufferLength,
    PVOID OutputBuffer,
    ULONG OutputBufferLength)
{
    if (IoControlCode == IOCTL_AFD_SEND)
    {
        const AFD_INFO* info = reinterpret_cast<AFD_INFO*>(InputBuffer);

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_XBUTTON1) < 0)
        {
            IoStatusBlock->Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
            IoStatusBlock->Pointer = nullptr;

            // I'm not entirely sure that I correctly calculate the length of all data, since there may be several buffers,
            // I tried to do it differently, but the process began to crash for me :/
            IoStatusBlock->Information = info->BufferArray->len;

            return STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }
    }

    // Calling the original function
    return pNtDeviceIoControlFile(FileHandle, Event, ApcRoutine, ApcContext, IoStatusBlock, IoControlCode, InputBuffer, InputBufferLength, OutputBuffer, OutputBufferLength);
}
```

The client considers that the data was successfully sent.

However, I do not understand how to make sure that the client does not see that some data has arrived? I tried to do something similar with `IOCTL_AFD_RECV`, but I was either disconnected from the server with an error, or the data was still read after the original function was called.

One of my old projects has a similar implementation, it uses intercepting the **[select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select)** function and setting `readfds->fd_count` to 0. However, after I resume receiving data, the data that I "missed" will still be received. And I need to drop them. If this is not possible, then, at least, how to do the same but using **[NtDeviceIoControlFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntdeviceiocontrolfile)**? I heard there is `IOCTL_AFD_SELECT`, but I couldn't find a structure to go to `readfds->fd_count` to 0.

upd: I found these two structures on the internet, but I still do not understand how to correctly call `FD_ZERO`

```
struct AFD_POLL_HANDLE_INFO
{
    HANDLE handle;
    ULONG events;
    NTSTATUS status;
};

struct AFD_POLL_INFO
{
    LARGE_INTEGER timeout;
    ULONG numberOfHandles;
    ULONG exclusive;
    AFD_POLL_HANDLE_INFO* handles;
};
```

Comment: your implementation of `myNtDeviceIoControlFile` is wrong. if `FileHandle` bound to I/O completion port, after success I/O must be packet queued to port. and application will be wait for this packet and handle result here (in pool or in callback from pool, which listen on iocp). so you can not return `STATUS_SUCCESS` without queue packet to iocp.

Comment: @RbMm, Do you mean that if I return `STATUS_SUCCESS` with `IOCTL_AFD_RECV`, then the application will think that some kind of packet has arrived? But if I return an error, it will terminate the connection.. I don't understand what I need to do.. :(

Comment: yes, of course, if socket bind to I/O port, application must receive packet after every synchronous failed I/O request.

Comment: It seems to me that the application knows that some data was received BEFORE calling `NtDeviceIoControlFile` with the IoControlCode `IOCTL_AFD_RECV` parameter. If I return `STATUS_PENDING` when I receive `IOCTL_AFD_RECV`, I am simply disconnected from the server. Please tell me how you can try to make it work :c

Comment: I think that the select informs the process that some data has arrived and only then `IOCTL_AFD_RECV` is called. How can I access the structure using the interception of the `NtDeviceIoControlFile` and `IOCTL_AFD_SELECT` functions? I can't find an her internet..

Comment: application can not know about *some data was received BEFORE calling NtDeviceIoControlFile* and application can not use *select* at all. i dont know what you try todo (your final target) and how it implement it. i simply say that you current implementation is wrong. it can work, if app not use iocp. but if it use it - will be undefined result

Comment: I need to make sure that while the condition is true, the application does NOT receive any data, as if they simply do not come.